# choosing Data Structure for efficient insertion of element

Tags: data-structures

Best Data Structure if we're not considering accesing of the element in the flow of problem solving. if only considering insertion and deletion cases frequently not accessing the element?

Comment: What are you inserting and deleting? How many deletes per insert? Is the structure expected to grow very large before shrinking again, or is expected to stay at roughly a constant size? How big are the items being stored? How many items are being inserted and deleted and how many items will be in the structure in the worst case? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For insertion and deletion, BS tree or RB tree is sufficient depends on data present.

Comment: Thanks for replying.